# Re-use template code in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've got a few routes set up like this:

```
this.route('posts', { 'path' : 'blog/' }, function() {
  this.route('category', { 'path' : 'category/:category' });
  this.route('post', { 'path' : '/:permalink' });
});
```

On posts I show all posts, on category only the ones specific for this post-category and on post only a single post.

All could re-use the same template to render a post but I don't quite understand how to accomplish this.

Can you explain me how to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a post partial. Please see [the guides for more info.](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper) Note that partial names have to start with an underscore.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I had to adapt it a bit myself since I'm using Ember Cli but it helped nonetheless.

Comment: @Henrik you're worried about the Ember Guides themselves becoming invalid?